# Nested placeholders replacing in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have strings with placeholders like "`{variant 1|variant 2}`", where "`|`" means "or"; I want to get all variants of strings without placeholders. For example, if I use string "`{a|b{c|d}}`", I get strings "`a`", "`bc`" and "`bd`". 
I tried to get it by regular expression `\{([^{}])\}` (it gets last level, in my case `{c|d}`) with recursion, but I have two strings on next step: `{a|bc}` and `{a|bd}`, which will produce "`a`", "`bc`", "`a`", "`bd`". May be I need to create some graph or tree structure?
I also want to ask about (?[^{}|$]*) 
Why there are "$"? I removed it, and have no effect.

Comment: Shouldn't `"{a|b{c|d}"` be `"{a|b{c|d}}"`?

Comment: Sorry :) Yes, it must have right syntax. I'll edit post.

Comment: `$string = str_replace('|', ',' $string); var_dump(\`/bin/bash -c 'echo $string'\`);` :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that |{} are reserved characters (not allowed as content of your variants, the following is a regex approach to the problem. Please note, that writing a simple state machine parser would be the better choice.

```
<?php // Using PHP5.3 syntax

// PCRE Recursive Pattern
// http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php

$string = "This test can be {very {cool|bad} in random order|or be just text} ddd {a|b{c|d}} bar {a|b{c{d|e|f}}} lala {b|c} baz";

if (preg_match_all('#\{((?>[^{}]+)|(?R))+\}#', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        // $match[0] == "{a|b{c|d}}" | "{a|b{c{d|e|f}}}" | "{b|c}"
        // have some fun splitting them up
        // I'd suggest walking the characters and building a tree
        // a simpler (slower, uglyer) approach:

        // remove {}
        $set = substr($match[0], 1, -1);
        while (strpos($set, '{') !== false) {
            // explode and replace nested {}
            // reserved characters: "{" and "}" and "|"
            // (?<=^|\{|\|) -- a substring needs to begin with "|" or "{" or be the start of the string,
            //  "?<=" is a positive look behind assertion - the content is not captured
            // (?<prefix>[^{|]+) -- is the prefix, preceeding literal string (anything but reserved characters)
            // \{(?<inner>[^{}]+)\} -- is the content of a nested {} group, excluding the "{" and "}"
            // (?<postfix>[^|}$]*) -- is the postfix, trailing literal string (anything but reserved characters)
            // readable: <begin-delimiter><possible-prefix>{<nested-group>}<possible-postfix>
            $set = preg_replace_callback('#(?<=^|\{|\|)(?<prefix>[^{}|]*)\{(?<inner>[^{}]+)\}(?<postfix>[^{}|$]*)#', function($m) {
                $inner = explode('|', $m['inner']);
                return $m['prefix'] . join($inner, $m['postfix'] . '|' . $m['prefix']) . $m['postfix'];
            }, $set);
        }

        // $items = explode('|', $set);
        echo "$match[0] expands to {{$set}}\n";
    }
}

/*
    OUTPUT:
    {very {cool|bad} in random order|or be just text} expands to {very cool in random order|very bad in random order|or be just text}
    {a|b{c|d}} expands to {a|bc|bd}
    {a|b{c{d|e|f}}} expands to {a|bcd|bce|bcf}
    {b|c} expands to {b|c}
*/
```

Comment: It looks cool, but for string $string = "This test can be {very {cool|bad} in random order|or be just text}" it returns incorrect result: {very {cool|bad} in random order|or be just text} expands to {very cool|very bad in random order|or be just text}

Comment: May be I can to fix this error... Can you to describe how works regexp #(?<=^|\{|\|)(?<prefix>[^{|]+)\{(?<inner>[^{}]+)\}# ?

Comment: your examples did not express the possibility of trailing characters. I've modified the regex to account for postfixes - it should now do what you expect it to.

Comment: Thank you very much! But can you to explain why you use "$" in postfix "exclude symbols" group?

Comment: the $ has no significance here. I just like to put ^ and $ into the sets (where applicable) to remind me of their existence. You may throw it out :)

Comment: Oh, thanks! Please write about your best practices for novice! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
$str = "This test can be {very {cool|bad} in random order|or be just text}";

function parseVarians($str, $buffer = array()) {
    if (empty($buffer)) $buffer['tokens'] = array();
    $newStr = preg_replace_callback('|\{([^{}]+)\}|', function($m) use(&$buffer) {
        $buffer['tokens'][] = explode('|', $m[1]);
        $index = count($buffer['tokens']) - 1;
        return '__' . $index;
    }, $str);

    if ($str != $newStr && strpos($newStr, '{') !== false) {
        return parseVarians($newStr, $buffer);
    }
    else {
        $buffer['str'] = $newStr;
        return $buffer;
    }
}

function devergeVariants($data) {
    krsort($data['tokens']);
    $strings  = array($data['str']);

    foreach ($data['tokens'] as $key => $token) {
        $variants = array();
        foreach ($token as $tok) {
            foreach ($strings as $str) {
                $variants[] = str_replace('__' . $key, $tok, $str);
            }
        }
        $strings = $variants;
    }

    return array_unique($strings);
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($str); echo '</pre>';

$tokens = parseVarians($str);
//echo '<pre>'; print_r($tokens); echo '</pre>';
$result = devergeVariants($tokens);

echo '<pre>'; print_r( $result ); echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
This test can be {very {cool|bad} in random order|or be just text}
Array
(
    [0] => This test can be very cool in random order
    [1] => This test can be or be just text
    [2] => This test can be very bad in random order
)
```

Seems like what you want?

Comment: Looks nice, but using array_unique: really you have duplicate of "This test can be or be just text" in $strings array.

Comment: Duplicates.. yes. This is a drawback of my algorithm.